# Allow ssh access for users with certain UID from certain IP's

Tags: linux, ssh, ip, ssh-config, uid

I need to allow ssh access to all users, but if the UID is between 6000 and 6500 I need to check if the IP where the ssh is coming from is in the file /etc/remote-hosts.

```
/etc/remote-hosts

1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
```

Any way to do this? I cannot find any information regarding this matter, only yo allow and block specific ip's or uid's.

Comment: How many users in the restricted range, how many unrestricted users and how many allowed IP addresses do you have? See https://askubuntu.com/q/649796 and [man sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config). There is also `AllowGroups`. Maybe you can use groups to grant different rights for restricted users and other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably the [pam_listfile](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile) module.

A block such as the following in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` will likely do what you want:

```
account [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid < 6000 uid > 6500
account required pam_listfile.so file=/etc/remote-hosts item=rhost sense=allow onerr=fail
```

The first line will skip over the `pam_listfile` test if the UID is outside the range 6000-6500. Remove the `quiet` flag to see when that test executes. Change it to `debug` to really fill your logs.

The second line will check if the user's remote host is in the access file. You can change that line to use `onerr=succeed`; if so, you can delete that access file to enable login for all users in that UID range.

And if I may suggest a modification to your strategy, instead of using a UID range, add such users to a common group, e.g. "restrictedssh". Then you don't have to worry about getting all such users into a specific UID range. Try the following block, instead:

```
account [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user notingroup restrictedssh
account required pam_listfile.so file=/etc/remote-hosts item=rhost sense=allow onerr=fail
```

In either case, add the lines near the top of your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file, right after any other `account` lines.

Comment: This solved my problem so easily. And thanks for the tip, will make sure to use it in the future but for now I have very specific requirements and your first suggestion works just fine!